# Align image to the center in Grid item Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Grid` from [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/). I dont know why image inside Grid item is align to the left and not to the center.

```js
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center" alignContent="center" style={{minHeight:"200px"}} >
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography style={{color:'white', textAlign:'center', fontSize:'2rem'}}>{name}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <a href={github} target="_blank">
                <img src={githubIcon} width="32px" height="32px" color="white"/>
              </a>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Also inside Typography I have to use `textAlign` to be in the center, but how to align an image?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, I editted code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try giving the Grid which wrapps the image, the `container` attribute and then center the image by adding `justify="center"` and / or `alignItems="center"` to this container.

Answer (score 0):

use this code intoyour grid tag.

alignContent='flex-start' alignItems='flex-start' justify='flex-start'

i got this from material ui docs [Material UI/Grid](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#grid-api.)